# How to merge xArray datasets with conflicting coordinates

Tags: python, python-xarray

Let's say I have two data sets, each containing a different variable of interest and with incomplete (but not conflicting) indices:

```
In [1]: import xarray as xr, numpy as np
In [2]: ages = xr.Dataset(
          {'ages': (['kid_ids'], np.random.rand((3))*20)}, 
          coords={'kid_names':(['kid_ids'], ['carl','kathy','gail']), 'kid_ids': [10,14,16]})
In [3]: heights = xr.Dataset(
          {'heights': (['kid_ids'], np.random.rand((3))*160)}, 
          coords={'kid_names':(['kid_ids'], ['carl','keith','gail']), 'kid_ids': [10,13,16]})
```

This creates two data sets that seem like they should merge well:

```
In [4]: ages
Out[4]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (kid_ids: 3)
Coordinates:
  * kid_ids    (kid_ids) int32 10 14 16
    kid_names  (kid_ids) <U5 'carl' 'kathy' 'gail'
Data variables:
    ages       (kid_ids) float64 13.28 1.955 4.327
In [5]: heights
Out[5]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (kid_ids: 3)
Coordinates:
  * kid_ids    (kid_ids) int32 10 13 16
    kid_names  (kid_ids) <U5 'carl' 'keith' 'gail'
Data variables:
    heights    (kid_ids) float64 115.0 38.2 31.65
```

but they don't - attempting `ages.merge(heights)` causes a `ValueError`:

```
ValueError: conflicting value for variable kid_names:
first value: <xarray.Variable (kid_ids: 4)>
array(['carl', nan, 'kathy', 'gail'], dtype=object)
second value: <xarray.Variable (kid_ids: 4)>
array(['carl', 'keith', nan, 'gail'], dtype=object)
```

dropping the coordinate `kid_names` solves the problem:

```
In [7]: ages.reset_coords('kid_names', drop=True).merge(
          heights.reset_coords('kid_names', drop=True))
Out[7]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (kid_ids: 4)
Coordinates:
  * kid_ids  (kid_ids) int64 10 13 14 16
Data variables:
    ages     (kid_ids) float64 0.4473 nan 6.45 6.787
    heights  (kid_ids) float64 78.42 78.43 nan 113.4
```

It seems as though the coordinates are being handled like `DataArrays`, in that any non-identical values raise an error. But shouldn't they be handled more like the base coordinates, e.g. extended to the superset of the two indices? Or is there another operation I should be doing?

I'm on python 3.5 using xarray 0.7.2 and numpy 1.10.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't currently easy to achieve in xarray, but it should be!

In fact, I think it should be safe to merge any non-conflicting values under most circumstances (unless the user requests higher scrutiny).

I opened a GitHub issue to track this: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/835

**Update**: the `merge` method now supports this by default (with `compat='no_conflicts'`), so `ages.merge(heights)` should just work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I had netcdf files with similar lat/long extent and similar variables/levels but with conflicting time steps (I had redownloaded them mistakefully!).
I used pandas to check if the time steps in each files is repeated in other files loaded in a list before. Finally I merged them without error.

`import xarray,os,shutil,numpy,pandas`             `files=os.listdir(os.path.join(place_in,variable,str(month),hour,level,extent))`

```
listed=[]
if len(files)!=0:
               add=os.path.join(place_in,variable,str(month),hour,level,extent,files[0])  
               data=xarray.open_dataset(add)
               listed=listed+[data]
               times=pandas.DataFrame(data.time.values,columns=["time"])
               for file in files[1:len(files)]:
                  add=os.path.join(place_in,variable,str(month),hour,level,extent,file)
                  data=xarray.open_dataset(add)
                  times1=pandas.DataFrame(data.time.values,columns=["time"])
                  times1=times1[~(times1["time"].isin(list(times["time"])))]
                  times=times.append(times1).drop_duplicates()
                  listed=listed+[data.sel(time=(numpy.array(times1['time'])))]
               data=xarray.merge(listed)
```